# Convex quadrilateral from many points

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

Does anyone know how to get (enclosing)‘convex quadrilateral’ from randomly scattered points?

The solution must have minimal area among the all possible quadrilaterals.

Any suggestion or conjectures would be welcomed.

Comment: [Related](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11580/minimum-area-bounding-quadrilateral-algorithm)

Comment: I think a lot of work has gone into the problem of finding a minimal enclosing circle, which I suspect is a simpler problem than a minimal enclosing quadrilateral. Maybe searching for discussions of the circle problem will give you some ideas for tackling the quadrilateral problem.

Comment: Any follow-up, plhn?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson I’m reading [doi:10.1007/BF01840359](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01840359) according to @SaucyO’Path’s related ilnk. :)